# wso2 : How to get SLA/ response time of service

Tags: wso2, esb, response-time

**how can i get response time of each services in ESB using class mediator?**

I created a DiscoveryProxy in ESB  and want to access QoS (response time) of services that have been deployed in application server.

how can i access to SLA/response time of services in  ESB?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the service stat details in the monitor-->System Statistics page.
If you need more fine grained details about your service,you might need to integrate BAM with AS.